# Send a safe link by e-mail to user access the Edit Action on my controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

[Sorry about my english]

I need to send by e-mail a safe link to the user access directly the Edit Action on my controller.
For example:
Send this link: *localhost:64148/Movies/Edit?id=4*
The problem is: If I send this link, the system will block the access because I'm using `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`

How can I send a safe link to the user, with a valid token or something like that?

Comment: The token is only used when POSTing an edit. People would be able to access Movies/Edit?id=4 just fine since it'll serve the GET, which is the edit form page. Also, you can't send people a localhost link because the app instance is only running on your machine, not a web server.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to send a link for a GET request. Since you don't modify any data with that link, it should not have a [ValidateAntiForgeryToken].